# Does PySCF use chemist's or physicist's notation for 1- and 2-electron integrals?

Tags: computational-chemistry, pyscf, integrals

I am trying to evaluate 1- and 2-electron integrals using PySCF trough this code:

```
Hij = mol.intor('int1e_kin') + mol.intor('int1e_nuc')
Vijkl = mol.intor('int2e')
```

where I previously defined `mol` in a particular basis.

I am new in this software and I am reading the basic tutorials that offers the project's site [here](https://pyscf.org/user/gto.html), but so far I can't find if the elements Vijkl of the 2-electron integrals are define in the chemist's notation,
$$
V_{ijkl} =
(ij|kl) =
\int \frac{\phi^*_i(\mathbf{r}_1)\phi_j(\mathbf{r}_1)\,\phi^*_k(\mathbf{r}_2)\phi_l(\mathbf{r}_2)}{|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|}\,d\mathbf{r}_1d\mathbf{r}_2,
$$
or physicist's notation, which is
$$
V_{ijkl} =
\langle ij|kl \rangle =
\int \frac{\phi^*_i(\mathbf{r}_1)\phi_j^*(\mathbf{r}_2)\,\phi_k(\mathbf{r}_1)\phi_l(\mathbf{r}_2)}{|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|}\,d\mathbf{r}_1d\mathbf{r}_2.
$$

I am assuming that the program uses chemist's notation. Am I right? And, if so, is it a way to easily convert the array into the other convention? Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: A quick google search with the keywords ```pyscf``` ```chemist notation``` and ```electron integrals``` gave these hits for [fci](https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.fci.html) and [cc](https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.cc.html). From these pages, they mention that **MO integrals are treated in chemist’s notation**.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas you can write an answer (please do!) and others can add more answers if they have anything more to add :)

Answer (score 6):

You are right that pyscf uses chemist's notation. A quick google search with the keywords `pyscf` `chemist notation` and `electron integrals` returned these two hits for [FCI](https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.fci.html) and [CC](https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.cc.html). Reading through the documentation, it is mentioned that the integrals are treated in chemist's notation.

To address the point that Prof. Dattani made, if you instead search for physicist's notation, you will find that as an argument for this function `pyscf.cc.gintermediates.get_t3p2_imds_slow` in the page for CC. I also found the mention of physicist's notation in this [page](https://pyscf.org/_modules/pyscf/pbc/cc/kccsd_t_rhf.html).

Comment: What about if you search "pyscf physicist notation"?

Comment: Thank you Prof. Dattani for raising an important point. I have added that in the answer.